# Why does every injured person in Game of Thrones refuse Milk of the Poppy?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I noticed Milk of the Poppy is offered every time some is near death.  Most people refuse it.  Is it refused because it will make you fall asleep and die?

Comment: This question would be improved (and quite possibly answered) by adding some quotes. Who, specifically, refuses it? If you can find a paragraph where they do, they may well also say why.

Comment: Offhand the only occasion I can remember is Jaime refusing it when Qyburn was about to treat the stump of his hand, because he feared that if he fell asleep he might wake up to discover they'd amputated his whole arm.